# Laravel 5 List users with bican roles

Tags: laravel-5, roles

I'm trying to list my staff members on a page by role.

I'm using [`Bican roles`](https://github.com/romanbican/roles).

I want to be able to display the user and then their (primary) role. Like this:

[image: Result]

Now, I have this code in my view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Forum team')

@section('content')

<div class="container" id="forum-container">

@foreach($roles as $role)
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="thread-box">
        <div class="thread-title">{{ $role->name }}</div>

        @if($role->id)
        <div class="forum-body">
            <div class="forum-user">
                <div class="user">Username <div class="{{ XenioNode\User::find(2)->isOnline() ? 'online' : 'offline' }}"></div></div>
                <img src="#" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre">
                <div class="user-status" style="background-color:blue;">Role name</div>
            </div>

            <div class="forum-thread-body">
                <div class="thread-body">
                    <p>The user's bio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endif

    </div>
</div>
@endforeach

</div>

@endsection
```

Then I have this in my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $GetRoles = DB::table('roles')->where('display', 1)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();
        $GetUsersByRole = DB::table('role_user')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();

        return view('team')->with('roles', $GetRoles)->with('userrole', $GetUsersByRole);
    }
```

So I want the User displayed in the correct field.

Like `Role ID` `1` is assigned to `User ID` `2`, then user ID `2` need to be in the place where role id `1` is.

Hope you understand

Kindest regards
Robin